# Total hours of 1 user gets shown on every user PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem that I am not understanding why it comes so.
this is the code:

```
function getHours($project_id, $project_startDate, $project_endDate)
{
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $users = $project->users()->get();

    $start_date = $project_startDate;
    $end_date = $project_endDate;

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $timesheetHours = $user->timesheets()->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])->get()->sum('hours');
    }
    return $timesheetHours;

}
```

I have 2 users in, and both of them have different hours, but it shows the same hours to them all.  tried many ways, even to foreach timesheetHours (ofc code was not like above). where am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the variable `$timesheetHours` in the second loop, you must use an array.

```
 foreach ($users as $user) {
        $timesheetHours[] = $user->timesheets()->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])->get()->sum('hours');
 }
 return $timesheetHours;
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ` this comes up, why?

Comment: loop the array then call htmlspecialchars() on each item

Comment: Where you used `htmlspecialchars()`? Share this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have to initialize the value first,and then foreach user you append the sum to it:

```
$timesheetHours = 0;
foreach ($users as $user) {
        $timesheetHours += $user->timesheets()->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])->get()->sum('hours');
 }
```

Comment: then it must be something with the query itself, try to execute `timesheets()->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])->get()->sum('hours');` foreach use manually (using `php artisan tinker`) and see if it outputs the correct hours count